# Admin table instead of user table in spatie/laravel-permission

Tags: php, laravel

i have created AdminMiddleware and i have written code as mention below but Auth::user will not work because i want to use Admin table instead of user table.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $Admin = \App\Admin::all()->count();
    if (!($Admin == 1)) {
        if (!Auth::user()->hasPermissionTo('Administer roles & permissions')) //If user does //not have this permission
        {
            abort('401');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `App\User` model class to `App\Admin` model class (you need to create it).

Edit file `config/auth.php` key `providers.users.model` set to `App\Admin`

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        // 'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
    ]
```

Comment: Admin have multiple roles which i want to manage through Admin, role and permission table and i want to create separate table of user for authorization than will it work in this case?

Comment: It is only "rename" `User` table/model to `Admin` table/model so I think that you can do everything you can do in standard (user table/model) approach.

Comment: if i will create another provider like providers.admin than how can i access in below snippet.

Auth::(what goes here)

Comment: `Auth::user()` will return `Admin` model object. So it will works without any changes (we not change auth methods)

Comment: That's okay i got it but i want `Auth::user()` for user table or user related authorisation so i don't want to change that. that's why i have asked you if i will create new provider than how can i access it?

Comment: In your question you write `i want to use Admin table instead of user table` - so I give you answer to this. If you wanna multi-user-tables authentication it is more complicated as far as I know - may be this will help you: https://scotch.io/@sukelali/how-to-create-multi-table-authentication-in-laravel or try to find some laravel library to do that